# Jupyter notebook Error - Kernel not connected

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, python-3.10

I am not too sure why I get an error "Not connected". I've been having this issue for sometime, so i tried uninstalling it and installing it again. Then after installing and launching jupyter notebook in the new env 'env39', I ran a line of code in a file. I also have python 3.10 and python 3.11 already installed in my Mac

```
[W 06:19:36.911 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 06:19:36.912 NotebookApp] Kernel 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a died, removing from map.
[W 06:20:18.745 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[E 06:20:18.750 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a)
[W 06:20:19.769 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:20:19.771 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 5.010000ms referer=None
[W 06:20:21.786 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:20:21.787 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 4.310000ms referer=None
[W 06:20:25.816 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:20:25.817 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 3.760000ms referer=None
[W 06:20:33.847 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:20:33.849 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 3.570000ms referer=None
[W 06:20:49.877 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:20:49.878 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 3.700000ms referer=None
[W 06:21:21.890 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:21:21.892 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 3.240000ms referer=None
[W 06:22:25.933 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a
[W 06:22:25.943 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/8b38d088-7fb5-415b-b69d-cb009c5fe34a/channels?session_id=35300b624bb44093b22d51f6f3d96dc7 (::1) 18.540000ms referer=None
```

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQWB.png)

After installing, here were the commands I ran:

```
(base) MacBook-Air:~ ayra.islam$ conda --version
conda 23.1.0
(base) MacBook-Air:~ ayra.islam$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/ayra.islam/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    beautifulsoup4-4.12.0      |  py310hecd8cb5_0         202 KB
    boltons-23.0.0             |  py310hecd8cb5_0         426 KB
    conda-23.3.1               |  py310hecd8cb5_0         973 KB
    conda-repo-cli-1.0.41      |  py310hecd8cb5_0         124 KB
    gettext-0.21.0             |       he85b6c0_1         3.0 MB
    jsonpatch-1.32             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          15 KB
    jsonpointer-2.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0           9 KB
    jupyter_core-5.3.0         |  py310hecd8cb5_0          91 KB
    libarchive-3.6.2           |       had00e1f_1         760 KB
    libclang-14.0.6            |default_hd95374b_1         138 KB
    libclang13-14.0.6          |default_habbcc1a_1         7.1 MB
    libllvm14-14.0.6           |       h91fad77_2        24.1 MB
    libxml2-2.10.3             |       h930c0e2_0         665 KB
    libxslt-1.1.37             |       h6d1eb0e_0         243 KB
    packaging-23.0             |  py310hecd8cb5_0          71 KB
    pkginfo-1.9.6              |  py310hecd8cb5_0          52 KB
    qt-main-5.15.2             |       h51e0635_8        44.6 MB
    qtwebkit-5.212             |       hbfab81c_5        10.6 MB
    requests-2.28.1            |  py310hecd8cb5_1          99 KB
    soupsieve-2.4              |  py310hecd8cb5_0          71 KB
    sqlite-3.41.2              |       h6c40b1e_0         1.2 MB
    tornado-6.2                |  py310hca72f7f_0         609 KB
    tqdm-4.65.0                |  py310h20db666_0         135 KB
    tzdata-2023c               |       h04d1e81_0         116 KB
    urllib3-1.26.15            |  py310hecd8cb5_0         196 KB
    zstd-1.5.5                 |       hc035e20_0         608 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        96.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  boltons            pkgs/main/osx-64::boltons-23.0.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  jsonpatch          pkgs/main/noarch::jsonpatch-1.32-pyhd3eb1b0_0 
  jsonpointer        pkgs/main/noarch::jsonpointer-2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0 
  libclang13         pkgs/main/osx-64::libclang13-14.0.6-default_habbcc1a_1 

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  alabaster-0.7.12-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  anyio-3.5.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  appdirs-1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  applaunchservices-0.3.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  appnope-0.1.2-py310hecd8cb5_1001
  appscript-1.1.2-py310hca72f7f_0
  argon2-cffi-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0-py310hca72f7f_0
  arrow-1.2.3-py310hecd8cb5_1
  astroid-2.14.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  astropy-5.1-py310h4e76f89_0
  asttokens-2.0.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  atomicwrites-1.4.0-py_0
  automat-20.2.0-py_0
  autopep8-1.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  babel-2.11.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  backcall-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  bcrypt-3.2.0-py310hca72f7f_1
  binaryornot-0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  black-22.6.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  blas-1.0-openblas
  bleach-4.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  blosc-1.21.3-hcec6c5f_0
  bokeh-2.4.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  bottleneck-1.3.5-py310h4e76f89_0
  brotli-1.0.9-hca72f7f_7
  brotli-bin-1.0.9-hca72f7f_7
  brunsli-0.1-h23ab428_0
  c-ares-1.18.1-hca72f7f_0
  cfitsio-3.470-hbd21bf8_7
  charls-2.2.0-h23ab428_0
  cloudpickle-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  colorama-0.4.6-py310hecd8cb5_0
  colorcet-3.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  comm-0.1.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  constantly-15.1.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  contourpy-1.0.5-py310haf03e11_0
  cookiecutter-1.7.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cssselect-1.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  curl-7.87.0-h6c40b1e_0
  cycler-0.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cytoolz-0.12.0-py310hca72f7f_0
  dask-2022.7.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  dask-core-2022.7.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  datashader-0.14.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  datashape-0.5.4-py310hecd8cb5_1
  debugpy-1.5.1-py310he9d5cce_0
  decorator-5.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  diff-match-patch-20200713-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  dill-0.3.6-py310hecd8cb5_0
  distributed-2022.7.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  docstring-to-markdown-0.11-py310hecd8cb5_0
  docutils-0.18.1-py310hecd8cb5_3
  entrypoints-0.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  executing-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  flake8-6.0.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  flask-2.2.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  flit-core-3.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  fonttools-4.25.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  fsspec-2022.11.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  gensim-4.3.0-py310h3ea8b11_0
  gmp-6.2.1-he9d5cce_3
  gmpy2-2.1.2-py310hd5de756_0
  greenlet-2.0.1-py310hcec6c5f_0
  h5py-3.7.0-py310h6c517f8_0
  hdf5-1.10.6-h10fe05b_1
  heapdict-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  holoviews-1.15.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  huggingface_hub-0.10.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  hvplot-0.8.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  hyperlink-21.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  imagecodecs-2021.8.26-py310hf5cf8d7_2
  imageio-2.26.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  imagesize-1.4.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  imbalanced-learn-0.10.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  importlib-metadata-4.11.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  importlib_metadata-4.11.3-hd3eb1b0_0
  incremental-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  inflection-0.5.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  iniconfig-1.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  intake-0.6.7-py310hecd8cb5_0
  intervaltree-3.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  ipykernel-6.19.2-py310h20db666_0
  ipython-8.10.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  ipywidgets-7.6.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  isort-5.9.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  itemadapter-0.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  itemloaders-1.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  itsdangerous-2.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jedi-0.18.1-py310hecd8cb5_1
  jellyfish-0.9.0-py310hca72f7f_0
  jinja2-time-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  jmespath-0.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  joblib-1.1.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jq-1.6-h9ed2024_1000
  json5-0.9.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyter-1.0.0-py310hecd8cb5_8
  jupyter_client-7.3.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jupyter_console-6.6.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jupyter_server-1.23.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab-3.5.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py_0
  jupyterlab_server-2.19.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jxrlib-1.1-haf1e3a3_2
  keyring-23.4.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  kiwisolver-1.4.4-py310hcec6c5f_0
  lazy-object-proxy-1.6.0-py310hca72f7f_0
  libaec-1.0.4-hb1e8313_1
  libbrotlicommon-1.0.9-hca72f7f_7
  libbrotlidec-1.0.9-hca72f7f_7
  libbrotlienc-1.0.9-hca72f7f_7
  libcurl-7.87.0-ha585b31_0
  libev-4.33-h9ed2024_1
  libgfortran-5.0.0-11_3_0_hecd8cb5_28
  libgfortran5-11.3.0-h9dfd629_28
  libllvm11-11.1.0-h46f1229_6
  libllvm12-12.0.0-h9b2ccf5_3
  libnghttp2-1.46.0-ha29bfda_0
  libopenblas-0.3.21-h54e7dc3_0
  libprotobuf-3.20.3-hfff2838_0
  libsodium-1.0.18-h1de35cc_0
  libspatialindex-1.9.3-h23ab428_0
  libssh2-1.10.0-h0a4fc7d_0
  libuv-1.44.2-h6c40b1e_0
  libzopfli-1.0.3-hb1e8313_0
  llvmlite-0.39.1-py310h8346a28_0
  locket-1.0.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  lxml-4.9.1-py310h65b224f_0
  lz4-3.1.3-py310hca72f7f_0
  lzo-2.10-haf1e3a3_2
  markdown-3.4.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  matplotlib-3.7.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  matplotlib-base-3.7.0-py310ha533b9c_0
  matplotlib-inline-0.1.6-py310hecd8cb5_0
  mccabe-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  mistune-0.8.4-py310hca72f7f_1000
  mock-4.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  mpc-1.1.0-h6ef4df4_1
  mpfr-4.0.2-h9066e36_1
  mpmath-1.2.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  msgpack-python-1.0.3-py310haf03e11_0
  multipledispatch-0.6.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  munkres-1.1.4-py_0
  mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py310hecd8cb5_1
  nbclassic-0.5.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  nbclient-0.5.13-py310hecd8cb5_0
  nbconvert-6.5.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  nest-asyncio-1.5.6-py310hecd8cb5_0
  networkx-2.8.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
  ninja-1.10.2-hecd8cb5_5
  ninja-base-1.10.2-haf03e11_5
  nltk-3.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  notebook-6.5.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  notebook-shim-0.2.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  numba-0.56.4-py310h3ea8b11_0
  numexpr-2.8.4-py310he50c29a_0
  numpy-1.23.5-py310he50c29a_0
  numpy-base-1.23.5-py310h992e150_0
  numpydoc-1.5.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  oniguruma-6.9.7.1-h9ed2024_0
  openjpeg-2.4.0-h66ea3da_0
  openpyxl-3.0.10-py310hca72f7f_0
  pandas-1.5.3-py310h3ea8b11_0
  pandocfilters-1.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  panel-0.14.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  param-1.12.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  parsel-1.6.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  parso-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  partd-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  pathspec-0.10.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  patsy-0.5.3-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pep8-1.7.1-py310hecd8cb5_1
  pexpect-4.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  plotly-5.9.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pooch-1.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  poyo-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  prometheus_client-0.14.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  prompt-toolkit-3.0.36-py310hecd8cb5_0
  prompt_toolkit-3.0.36-hd3eb1b0_0
  protego-0.1.16-py_0
  ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  pure_eval-0.2.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  py-1.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyasn1-0.4.8-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyasn1-modules-0.2.8-py_0
  pycodestyle-2.10.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pyct-0.5.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pycurl-7.45.1-py310h0a4fc7d_0
  pydispatcher-2.0.5-py310hecd8cb5_2
  pydocstyle-6.3.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pyerfa-2.0.0-py310hca72f7f_0
  pyflakes-3.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pygments-2.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyhamcrest-2.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  pylint-2.16.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pylint-venv-2.3.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pyls-spyder-0.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyobjc-core-9.0-py310h9205ec4_1
  pyobjc-framework-cocoa-9.0-py310h9205ec4_0
  pyobjc-framework-coreservices-9.0-py310h46256e1_0
  pyobjc-framework-fsevents-9.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pyodbc-4.0.34-py310he9d5cce_0
  pyparsing-3.0.9-py310hecd8cb5_0
  pyqtwebengine-5.15.7-py310he9d5cce_0
  pytables-3.7.0-py310h59775c6_1
  pytest-7.1.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  python-lsp-black-1.2.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  python-lsp-jsonrpc-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-lsp-server-1.7.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  python-slugify-5.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-snappy-0.6.1-py310hcec6c5f_0
  pytoolconfig-1.2.5-py310hecd8cb5_1
  pytorch-1.12.1-cpu_py310h64f2f56_1
  pyviz_comms-2.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pywavelets-1.4.1-py310h6c40b1e_0
  pyzmq-23.2.0-py310he9d5cce_0
  qdarkstyle-3.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  qstylizer-0.2.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  qtawesome-1.2.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  qtconsole-5.4.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  queuelib-1.5.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  regex-2022.7.9-py310hca72f7f_0
  requests-file-1.5.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  rope-1.7.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  rtree-1.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  scikit-image-0.19.3-py310hcec6c5f_1
  scikit-learn-1.2.1-py310hcec6c5f_0
  scipy-1.10.0-py310ha516a68_1
  scrapy-2.8.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  seaborn-0.12.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  send2trash-1.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  service_identity-18.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  smart_open-5.2.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  snappy-1.1.9-he9d5cce_0
  sniffio-1.2.0-py310hecd8cb5_1
  snowballstemmer-2.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sortedcontainers-2.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinx-5.0.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  spyder-5.4.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  spyder-kernels-2.4.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  sqlalchemy-1.4.39-py310hca72f7f_0
  stack_data-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  statsmodels-0.13.5-py310h7b7cdfe_1
  sympy-1.11.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  tabulate-0.8.10-py310hecd8cb5_0
  tbb-2021.7.0-ha357a0b_0
  tbb4py-2021.7.0-py310ha357a0b_0
  tblib-1.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tenacity-8.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_1
  terminado-0.17.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  text-unidecode-1.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  textdistance-4.2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  threadpoolctl-2.2.0-pyh0d69192_0
  three-merge-0.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tifffile-2021.7.2-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  tinycss2-1.2.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  tldextract-3.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tokenizers-0.11.4-py310h8776b5c_1
  tomli-2.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  tomlkit-0.11.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  transformers-4.24.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  twisted-22.2.0-py310hca72f7f_1
  typing-extensions-4.4.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  typing_extensions-4.4.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  unidecode-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  unixodbc-2.3.11-hb456775_0
  w3lib-1.21.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  watchdog-2.1.6-py310h999c104_0
  wcwidth-0.2.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  webencodings-0.5.1-py310hecd8cb5_1
  websocket-client-0.58.0-py310hecd8cb5_4
  werkzeug-2.2.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  whatthepatch-1.0.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  widgetsnbextension-3.5.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  wrapt-1.14.1-py310hca72f7f_0
  wurlitzer-3.0.2-py310hecd8cb5_0
  xarray-2022.11.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  xlwings-0.29.1-py310hecd8cb5_0
  yapf-0.31.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  zeromq-4.3.4-h23ab428_0
  zfp-0.5.5-he9d5cce_6
  zict-2.1.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  zipp-3.11.0-py310hecd8cb5_0
  zope-1.0-py310hecd8cb5_1
  zope.interface-5.4.0-py310hca72f7f_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  beautifulsoup4                     4.11.1-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 4.12.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  conda                              23.1.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 23.3.1-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  conda-repo-cli                     1.0.27-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 1.0.41-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  gettext                                 0.21.0-h7535e17_0 --> 0.21.0-he85b6c0_1 
  jupyter_core                        5.2.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 5.3.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  libarchive                               3.6.2-h65c5294_0 --> 3.6.2-had00e1f_1 
  libclang                        12.0.0-default_hbc2896b_2 --> 14.0.6-default_hd95374b_1 
  libllvm14                               14.0.6-h91fad77_1 --> 14.0.6-h91fad77_2 
  libxml2                                 2.9.14-hbf8cd5e_0 --> 2.10.3-h930c0e2_0 
  libxslt                                 1.1.35-h5b33f42_0 --> 1.1.37-h6d1eb0e_0 
  packaging                            22.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 23.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  pkginfo                             1.8.3-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 1.9.6-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  qt-main                                 5.15.2-h719ae48_7 --> 5.15.2-h51e0635_8 
  qtwebkit                                 5.212-h24dc246_4 --> 5.212-hbfab81c_5 
  requests                           2.28.1-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 2.28.1-py310hecd8cb5_1 
  soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 2.4-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  sqlite                                  3.40.1-h880c91c_0 --> 3.41.2-h6c40b1e_0 
  tornado                               6.1-py310hca72f7f_0 --> 6.2-py310hca72f7f_0 
  tqdm                               4.64.1-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 4.65.0-py310h20db666_0 
  tzdata                                   2022g-h04d1e81_0 --> 2023c-h04d1e81_0 
  urllib3                           1.26.14-py310hecd8cb5_0 --> 1.26.15-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  zstd                                     1.5.2-hcb37349_0 --> 1.5.5-hc035e20_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                
Preparing transaction: done                                                     
Verifying transaction: done                                                     
Executing transaction: done                                                     
(base) MacBook-Air:~ ayra.islam$ conda create --name env39 python=3.10          
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done                       
Solving environment: done                                                       
                                                                                
## Package Plan ##                                                              
                                                                                
  environment location: /Users/ayra.islam/anaconda3/envs/env39                  
                                                                                
  added / updated specs:                                                        
    - python=3.10                                                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
The following packages will be downloaded:                                      
                                                                                
    package                    |            build                               
    ---------------------------|-----------------                               
    pip-23.0.1                 |  py310hecd8cb5_0         2.6 MB                
    python-3.10.10             |       h218abb5_2        13.2 MB                
    ------------------------------------------------------------                
                                           Total:        15.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bzip2              pkgs/main/osx-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h1de35cc_0 
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/osx-64::ca-certificates-2023.01.10-hecd8cb5_0 
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-64::certifi-2022.12.7-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  libffi             pkgs/main/osx-64::libffi-3.4.2-hecd8cb5_6 
  ncurses            pkgs/main/osx-64::ncurses-6.4-hcec6c5f_0 
  openssl            pkgs/main/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1t-hca72f7f_0 
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-23.0.1-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.10.10-h218abb5_2 
  readline           pkgs/main/osx-64::readline-8.2-hca72f7f_0 
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-65.6.3-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  sqlite             pkgs/main/osx-64::sqlite-3.41.2-h6c40b1e_0 
  tk                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tk-8.6.12-h5d9f67b_0 
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2023c-h04d1e81_0 
  wheel              pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.38.4-py310hecd8cb5_0 
  xz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::xz-5.2.10-h6c40b1e_1 
  zlib               pkgs/main/osx-64::zlib-1.2.13-h4dc903c_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                
Preparing transaction: done                                                     
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate env39
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) MacBook-Air:~ ayra.islam$
```

I don't really understand why I still get the noted error. Could someone please explain why this might be the case and how I could resolve it?

Thanks :)